# How many times can a positive integer be written as the sum of $n$ numbers or less, where each addend is between 1 and 9?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I am asking to know how many numbers there are with $n$ digits such that the sum of their digits is $d$. Zero is excluded as a possible digit.

I need to prove a problem in which I show that there exists at least one $x$ in some interval dependent of $a$ such that the sum of the digits of $F(xa)$ is equal to $x$. I can detail the whole problem if you want, but I'm really only looking for this one property.

Edit: I have found the answer [in this paper.](http://www.gallup.unm.edu/~smarandache/SN/ScArt4/NumberOfNumbers.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried looking at (say) 2-digit numbers? Is zero excluded completely, or just from the leading position?

Comment: @Matthew Conroy: I need to prove a problem in which I show that there exists at least one x in some interval dependant of a such that the sum of the digits of F(xa) is equal to x. I can detail the whole problem if you want, but I'm really only looking for this one property.

Comment: @Joffan: zero is completely excluded, but it's irrelevant. Essentially you could reword my question to "How many times can a positive integer be written as the sum of n numbers between 0 and 9 inclusive?"

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** rules of the game:

- **s(x)** = sum of digits of positive integer **x** in decimal notation;
- **d(x)** = *length* of positive integer **x** in decimal notation $\to$ the number of digits in decimal notation; so **d(x) = n**, as referred to in the question.

It should be obvious that $$\forall x \in \Bbb{N}, 1 \le s(x) \le 9 \cdot d(x) = 9 \cdot n$$so$$s(x) \le 0 \vee s(x) > 9 \cdot n \Rightarrow \text{no solution!}$$
..Now, the question focuses on finding how many **x** of $n$ digits are there $|0 \lt s(x) \le 9 \cdot n$. Well, if we exclude the case when $x = 999\cdots99$, there is always a digit in the decimal representation of **x** that is less than **9** $\Rightarrow$ given **x** $|s(x) = k$, we can always find a **y** $|s(y) = k+1$ by increasing by one any of the digit of **x**..so there is **at least** one **x** of **n** digits such that $0 < s(x) < 9\cdot n$, and **exactly** one **x** of **n** digits such that $s(x) = 9\cdot n$.